# Summing some words occurenses table

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am working on a logic challenge at the moment as part of a project and have been working for hours trying to solve it. I have:

```
data = [
  ["this is a list of words", "2"],
  ["another list of words", "2"]
]
```

And I want to return this:

```
data = [
  ["this", "2"],
  ["is", "2"],
  ["a", "2"],
  ["list", "4"],
  ["of", "4"],
  ["another", "2"],
  ["words", "4"]
]
```

essentially, the string of words in index position [0] get split and any duplicates get removed but index [1] gets added if there is a duplicate.

I have tried many things, splitting, and using propigation as well as countless iterations but everything seems to hit a dead end. I'm sure there is quite a simple solution.

This is my latest attempt:

```
  #Loop through each data item
  data.each do |obj| 
    # create each obj to an array and save to var
    newObj = obj.permutation(1).to_a 
    # loop through array of words and split storing the count
    split_query = newObj[0].each do |e| 
     query_count = e.split(' ').count
     print e.split(' ')
    end
  end
```

Comment: It is worth adding one of your tries. There is a good chance it solves some part of the problem already, even if you are stuck. Then you can get help specific to the bit of Ruby you need to learn, rather than just the solution.

Comment: Sure, I've edited above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary:

```
hash = Hash.new {0}
data.each do |v|
  x = v[1].to_i
  v[0].split.each do |word|
    hash[word] += x
  end
end
result = hash.map {|k,v| [k, v.to_s]}
```

yields:

```
result
=> [["this", "2"],
    ["is", "2"],
    ["a", "2"],
    ["list", "4"],
    ["of", "4"],
    ["words", "4"],
    ["another", "2"]]
```

Comment: It is more idiomatic to use `.each` instead of a `for ... in` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that as follows.

**Code**

```
def tally(data)
  data.flat_map { |str,val| str.split.product([val.to_i]) }.
       group_by(&:first).
       map { |_,arr| [arr.first.first, arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,val)| t+val }.to_s] }
end
```

**Example**

```
data = [
  ["this is a list of words", "2"],
  ["another list of words", "2"],
  ["yet one more list", "3"],
  ["and a final one", "4"]]
tally data
  #=> [["this", "2"], ["is", "2"], ["a", "6"], ["list", "7"],
  #    ["of", "4"], ["words", "4"], ["another", "2"], ["yet", "3"],
  #    ["one", "7"], ["more", "3"], ["and", "4"], ["final", "4"]]
```

It probably would be more useful to return pairs having the count expressed as an integer rather than a string.

**Explanation**

For the example, these are the step-by-step calculations:

```
a = data.flat_map { |str,val| str.split.product([val.to_i]) }
  #=> [["this", 2], ["is", 2], ["a", 2], ["list", 2], ["of", 2],
  #    ["words", 2], ["another", 2], ["list", 2], ["of", 2],
  #    ["words", 2], ["yet", 3], ["one", 3], ["more", 3], ["list", 3],    
  #    ["and", 4], ["a", 4], ["final", 4], ["one", 4]] 
b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {"this"=>[["this", 2]],
  #    "is"=>[["is", 2]],
  #    "a"=>[["a", 2], ["a", 4]],
  #    "list"=>[["list", 2], ["list", 2], ["list", 3]],
  #    "of"=>[["of", 2], ["of", 2]],
  #    "words"=>[["words", 2], ["words", 2]],
  #    "another"=>[["another", 2]],
  #    "yet"=>[["yet", 3]],
  #    "one"=>[["one", 3], ["one", 4]],
  #    "more"=>[["more", 3]],
  #    "and"=>[["and", 4]],
  #    "final"=>[["final", 4]]} 
b.map { |_,arr| [arr.first.first, arr.reduce(0) { |t,(_,val)| t+val }.to_s] }
  #=> (the result for the example shown above)
```

**Hash alternative**

It is more natural to use a hash here, with values being integers. For that we define the hash using [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) with a default value of zero:

```
def tally(data)
  data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(str,val),h|
    str.split.each { |word| h[word] += val.to_i }
  end
end

h = tally(data)
  #=> {"this"=>2, "is"=>2, "a"=>6, "list"=>7, "of"=>4, "words"=>4,
  #    "another"=>2, "yet"=>3, "one"=>7, "more"=>3, "and"=>4, "final"=>4}
```

If you would prefer the keys to be in decreasing order of value:

```
sorted_keys = h.keys.sort_by { |k| -h[k] }
  #=> ["one", "list", "a", "of", "and", "words", "final", "yet",
  #    "more", "another", "is", "this"] 
sorted_keys.zip(h.values_at(*sorted_keys)).to_h
  #=> {"one"=>7, "list"=>7, "a"=>6, "of"=>4, "and"=>4, "words"=>4,
  #   "final"=>4, "yet"=>3, "more"=>3, "another"=>2, "is"=>2, "this"=>2}
```

`Hash.new(0)` is often called a "counting hash". If:

```
h = Hash.new(0)
```

then:

```
h[:a] += 1
```

is equivalent to:

```
h[:a] = h[:a] + 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `:a` (as is the case when `h` is empty), `h[:a]` on the right side of the equation equals the hash's *default value*, given by `new`'s argument, here zero. Therefore:

```
h[:a] = h[:a] + 1
  #   = 0 + 1
  #   = 1 
h #=> { :a => 1 }
```

The next time we encounter the key `:a`:

```
h[:a] += 1
  #=> h[:a] = h[:a] + 1
  #=>       = 1 + 1
  #=>       = 2
```